# Radio Buttons in Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, survey, mvc-editor-templates

I am in the process of creating a 'Progress Report' with a list of questions and multiple choice answers.  The questions are populated into the Progress Report automatically via a separate unrelated process in case it is relevant.

Code is as follows:
Edit View:

```
@model App.Models.ProgressReport
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportAnswers)
```

ReportAnswer.cshtml EditorTemplate (which shows the question and the answer from the Progress Report):

```
@model App.Models.ReportAnswer    
<h3>
    Question
</h3>

<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Question.QuestionText)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Question.PossibleAnswers)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AnswerID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerID)
</p>
```

PossibleAnswer.cshtml (Editor Template which shows all available answers to the question):

```
@model App.Models.PossibleAnswer

<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AnswerText)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.AnswerText, Model.AnswerID,  new { Name =Model.QuestionID })
</p>
```

So this displays all associated questions from the Progress Report and the optional answers.

My problems:

1.)  Is that each radio button has a different name which allows me to select all answers for a single question instead of unselecting one as the next is selected.

2.)  The selected answer should load as selected the next time I edit the progress report.  How to have one of the answers pre-selected on load based on the answer provided the last time the view was loaded.

3.)  How to return the selected answer back to the Edit action in my ProgressReport Controller?

Thanks a bunch for any assistance

EditController Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include =  "ReportID,ClientID,ReportDateSubmitted,ReportWeek")] ProgressReport progressReport)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(progressReport).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ID", progressReport.ClientID);
        return View(progressReport);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the use of an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `PossibleAnswer`. The `EditorFor()` method is designed to work with collections and add an prefixes and indexers to the property same so that it can be bound to a collection by the `DefaultModelBinder` on post back. The second issue is that your binding the radio buttons to property `AnswerText` of `PossibleAnswer`, when you should be binding to `AnswerID` property of `ReportAnswer`.

Delete the `PossibleAnswer.cshtml` file and modify the `ReportAnswer.cshtml` to

```
@model App.Models.ReportAnswer    
<h3>Question</h3>
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Question.QuestionText)</p>
@foreach(var answer in Model.Question.PossibleAnswers)
{
  var id = string.Format("answer-{0}", answer.AnswerID);
  <p>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AnswerID, answer.AnswerID, new { id = id })
    <label for="@id">@answer.AnswerText</label>    
  </p>
}
```

This will generate html that looks like

```
<input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="[0].AnswerID" value="1" />
<label for="answer-1">Answer 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="[0].AnswerID" value="2" />
<label for="answer-2">Answer 2</label>
```

Side note: **NEVER** attempt to override the `name` attribute (as in your usage of `new { Name = Model.QuestionID }`. There is no surer way to guarantee model binding will fail :)

Comment: That works perfectly now!  Except for actually posting the answers when the Progress Report is posted.  I have added my controller code to the original post.  Forgot that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _posting the answers_? You don't (and should not) be rendering controls for all properties of `PossibleAnswers`. You should be just posting the selected `AnswerID` for each question. If you need to return the view (which your should only ever do if `ModelState` is invalid), then you need to repopulate the collections of answers for each question.

Comment: And remove that dreadful `[Bind(Include = "..")]` attribute! If you have properties that you want to exclude from binding, use a view model(s) with only those properties your need to display/edit (and then you can also include properties for the `SelectList` and get rid of `ViewBag`)

Comment: Sorry about the Bind(Include..) automated thing and didnt know I shouldnt use it.  :)  When I post the edit with the selected answers, I would like to record those selected answers back into the database.  So yes, Just AnswerID and of course the PK ID.  I am not sure how to do that?  Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: I assume by PK ID, you mean the questions ID property but you don't appear to have included a hidden input for it in the view (so it does not post back). I don't know enough about you models and database, but you can access the values using something like `foreach (ReportAnswer answer in progressReport.ReportAnswers) { int questionID = answer.QuestionID; int answerID = answer.AnswerID; // save the values to the database? }`

Comment: Perfect!  You led me in the right direction and now all my problems are solved...at least with regards to this post. :)  It was indeed that I needed to include the hidden inputs and your foreach loop got me going so I could finish it up.  Will post the final result.

Comment: Just one additional issue associated with this.  When I attempted to make the answer fields required and I submit with missing data it makes the model invalid (good), but the Edit controller is not returning the progressReport with associated questions thereby causing an error in the editor template parsing out the questions/answers.

Comment: Unless you include inputs for all your properties in the view, you need to repopulate your model if you return your view. This is a balancing act - posting back a lot of extra inputs vs repopulating data from the db in the controller. But you should use client side validation (`jquery.validate.unobtrusive`) in conjunction with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so that an invalid model will not be submitted in the first place and minimize the need to return the view.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I will look into implementing client side validation.      Hopefully will be able to implement without posting another question...  Thanks for your help!